# When trying to add my helper class in bridging header file getting error

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header

I Have swift project which contains some objc helper classes so i've added a bridging header file `LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header.h` i am trying add `IAPHelper` which contains `RMStore.h` file but after adding the `IAPHelper` into Bridging header file getting error like this

```
fatal error: file '/Users/iosdev/Desktop/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/iosdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LiveWallpapers-fwqqyradpdlkpffqjjjyrrtjxglv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header-swift_2PVFNGTY415W9-clang_GDHQ1O60MXTQ.pch' was built
note: please rebuild precompiled header '/Users/iosdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LiveWallpapers-fwqqyradpdlkpffqjjjyrrtjxglv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header-swift_2PVFNGTY415W9-clang_GDHQ1O60MXTQ.pch'
/Users/iosdev/Desktop/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header.h:10:9: note: in file included from /Users/iosdev/Desktop/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header.h:10:
#import "IAPHelper.h"
        ^
/Users/iosdev/Desktop/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers/Objc/IAPHelper.h:11:9: error: 'RMStore.h' file not found
#import "RMStore.h"
        ^
1 error generated.
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/iosdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LiveWallpapers-fwqqyradpdlkpffqjjjyrrtjxglv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header-swift_2PVFNGTY415W9-clang_GDHQ1O60MXTQ.pch' for bridging header '/Users/iosdev/Desktop/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I tried to add `RMStore.h` in bridging Header file then getting error as below

```
/Users/iosdev/Desktop/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header.h:10:9: error: 'RMStore.h' file not found
#import "RMStore.h"
        ^
1 error generated.
<unknown>:0: error: failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/iosdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LiveWallpapers-fwqqyradpdlkpffqjjjyrrtjxglv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header-swift_2PVFNGTY415W9-clang_GDHQ1O60MXTQ.pch' for bridging header '/Users/iosdev/Desktop/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers/LiveWallpapers-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: 'RMStore.h' file not found  try  to add  'RMStore.h'  to your project or remove it if you don't need it

Comment: @AliAdam When i tried to add "RMStore.h" in bridging header still getting error update with error in question.

Comment: not only   in bridging header add it  your project

Comment: added in bridging header and Prefix header still same error.

Comment: check this file if it is exist or not in your project

Comment: oops i tried "RMStore/RMStore.h" and it worked .

Answer (score 0):

check your 'RMStore.h' file on your project, if its textcolor is red it was deleted from your project, copy your file on project folder then drag and drop on your project. 
clean and build